# what could be the reason not called completionHandler in uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:progress:completionHandler: iOS8

Tags: ios7, ios8, afnetworking-2

AFNetworking pods:
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2'

When I upload some file via AFURLSessionManager -uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:progress:completionHandler: and was lost internet connection on iOS 7 completionHandler called with error, but in iOS 8 - not at all called.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find the solution?